# Did the book make a mistake in the identity$\frac{1}{\cos 2x+\tan x} = \sin 2x$?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

EDIT: OP says that they misread the text from which this question was drawn. It actually said $$\frac{1}{\cot(2x) + \tan(x)} = \sin(2x)$$

where $\cos$ has been replaced by $\cot$; that identity is true for all $x$. Original question follows.

---

Since it is identical to, I decided out of the blue that before I start to work out the question for a value of $x$, I took $x=\pi$.

LHS: $$\frac{1}{\cos(2\pi)+\tan(\pi)}=1$$

RHS: $$\sin(2\pi)=0$$

Which clearly shows that they are not identical... could it be that it might have been a misprint?

Comment: Are you sure that it's an identity and not an equation? Since you said that you were going to work out a value of $x$, then it need not be an identity. For example, the equation $x - 2 = 0$ can be worked out for a value of $x$ but the $\mathrm{LHS} \neq \mathrm{RHS}$ for all $x \neq 2$.

Comment: It is an equation to solve for $x$.

Comment: Nah it was my fault i misread cot2x for cos2x ....

Comment: $(\cot (2x)+\tan x)(\sin (2x))=\cos (2x)+\frac{\sin x \sin(2x)}{\cos x}=\cos (2x)+2\sin^2 x=1$, where I used $\cot y=\frac{1}{\tan y}=\frac{\cos y}{\sin y}$, $\sin (2y)=2\sin y\cos y$ and $\cos (2x)=1-2\sin^2 x$.